# Adding extra property to root property of JSON object from .NET Serialized string in asmx web method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, web-services, asmx

Suppose we're serializing a .NET object of class "Thing".  Our root property of our JSON object is "d" when a proxy receives the JSON response.  Is there a way to add a property to the root property, or a sibling property to the JSON objects from ASP.NET in an asmx web method?  Right now, I have a hack.. I am putting the value as an extra parameter in each 'Thing' object in my JSON object.

**Thing class and web service ASP.NET code:**

```
namespace Web.Controls.ThingList
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ThingListService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class Thing
        {
            public string id;
            public string name;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        public List<Thing> GetThingList(string start, string limit)  //
        {
            return GetList("Thing", start, limit);
        }

    }
}
```

**JSON object:**

```
{
    "d": [{
        "__type": "Web.Controls.ThingList.ThingListService+Thing",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "ONE"
    }, {
        "__type": "Web.Controls.ThingList.ThingListService+Thing",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "TWO"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, as a sibling to `d`? I don't think so, unfortunately.  Wrapping the response with `d` was a security feature implemented in .NET 3.5.

Comment: sure, that's fine.. I just want an extra value being passed back to the JavaScript code in the JSON object

Comment: so should I just make a global response class (Serialized) with property List<Thing> and this extra property?  And pass that instead of List<Thing>?

Comment: You might have to build your own wrapper: `ThingWrapper`, that has you extra property and also the list of `Thing`s. But that probably means rewriting a lot of your client side code...

Comment: I think you just read my mind!

Comment: In the ExtJS book I'm reading, the php server proxy seems to pass back d.totalProperty.  Good to know that ASP.NET won't support their standard paging behavior.  This property just tells the client how many records it found for the paging toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it:**

```
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        model: 'Thing',
        totalProperty: 'd.recordCount',
        idProperty: 'id',
        root: 'd.resultSet'
    },


[Serializable]
public class ProxyResponse
{
    public string recordCount;
    public List<Thing> resultSet;
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public ProxyResponse GetThingList(string start, string limit)  //
{
    ProxyResponse response = new ProxyResponse();

    List<Thing> list = GetList("Thing", start, limit);

    response.recordCount = list.Count.ToString();
    response.resultSet = list;

    return response;
}
```

Comment: +1 to the question, I was hoping to figure this one out myself.  I just wish there could be an easy answer that doesn't modify the response in a way that breaks existing clients :(

Comment: Well, if your response is being sent by Microsoft web services, you must wrap the JSON with root "d" because of their requirement starting in .NET 3.5.  Because you need to pass extra values (besides the result set) back to the client, you must do it this way unless you want to make two web service calls.  But then you have to deal with asynchronous calls, which means one success function must wait for the other success function to finish successfully.  It's just more overhead.